# Cannot compile Rust code on macOS 10.12: object file was built for newer OSX version (10.7) than being linked (8.0)

Tags: macos, rust

Experimenting with Rust, I didn't get that far as there is a configuration issue with my C compiler. On attempting to compile the Hello World example (using `rustc main.rs` according to the getting started docs), I am seeing an enormous amount of warnings like this:

```
ld: warning: object file (/Users/sinewave440hz/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-66cfa4df0876a39d.rlib(jemalloc.pic.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.7) than being linked (8.0)
```

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6

`cc -v`:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

`rustc --version`:

```
rustc 1.26.1 (827013a31 2018-05-25)
```

Comment: "8.0" does not look like a macOS version, it looks like an *iOS version*. Are you attempting to cross-compile?

Comment: I'm just following the getting started docs, basic stuff.

Comment: How did you install the command line dev tools? Have you attempted to compile for iOS before? Would you have ever created a `.cargo/config` file anywhere?

Comment: As far as I recall, I installed with the usual `xcode-select --install`. I have certainly used the c compiler previously for various purposes, but have never created a `.cargo/config` file. I think I will try a re-install of the dev tools.

Comment: No change after reinstalling dev tools, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any environment variables set, such as `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`? Anything like `CFLAGS`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I'm away from my work machine until Monday. Last night I successfully ran on another machine running High Sierra, after reinstalling dev tools and (this made the difference) restarting! I will do that and check the env vars on monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments I had the opportunity to duplicate the process on another machine, which led me to believe that restarting macOS after installing the dev tools would make a difference. Sure enough, the app compiled and ran without issue after restarting, so there must have been some environment variables that needed resetting/updating (I don't suppose it's that relevant which ones, when it's so easily solved...).